# Php - String Search

Tags: php, string, function

```
$string = '$12.50 - This is my string';
```

This is my string & I want remove section from `$` to first space using php string function. I have tried `substr` but it returns me string after `$`.

Output should be as below:

```
- This is my string
```

In some cases there is no $ sign ain first place of string so in those cases "This" is removed from string.

Comment: Will the $ always be the first character in the string?

Comment: @Jan yes $ will always in beginning of string..

Comment: In the string, or at the beginning of the string?

Comment: And no one ever think of poor [fscanf](http://php.net/fscanf)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sub = substr($string, strpos($string, " "));
```

You may need to use `strpos($string, " ") + 1` depending on if you want that extra space.

([strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) finds the first occurence of a character.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '$12.50 - This is my string';
$string = strstr($string, ' ');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**explode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$string = '$12.50 - This is my string';
$test = explode(" ", $string, 2);
echo $test[1];
```

Comment: @MarkMartin: If my asnwer has worked, then can you please accept it as answer?

Comment: @MarkMartin: I dont understand the reason for un-accepting the answer. Can you kindly mention the reason in comment. Not complaining, just curious to improve my answer in accordance with the problem you have faced.

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_replace:

```
$string = '$12.50 - This is my string';

echo preg_replace('/^(.*?)\s/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Hello,
Sorry to say but in some cases there is no $ sign in string...so when i apply this logic in some cases "This" is removed from string.
In some cases string will be
    $string = "This is my string";